# Как перенести элемент на задний план WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Установил библиотеку MediaPlayerWpf и возникла проблема при наложении на передний план других объектов. Xaml такого вида

```
<ui:MediaPlayerWpf Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="Player" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Opacity="0.5">
    <mpw:MpvMediaPlayerHost  IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="PlayerHost" Visibility="Hidden" IsVisibleChanged="player_change" d:IsLocked="True"/>
</ui:MediaPlayerWpf>                               
<Button Style="{StaticResource PlayButton}" Width="100" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Play_in_Player" x:Name="PlayB2" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выставить mpw:MpvMediaPlayerHost Visibility="Visible"

То все объекты которые должны быть перед плеером..попадают на задний план.

Сразу же пропал Button
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же ListBox с живым поиском попадает на задний план.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, понятия не имею, как исправить этот баг. Z.Index тут не работает ")

Comment: А другую программу можно открыть сверху? Или видео и ее перекрывает?

Comment: `mpw:MpvMediaPlayerHost` Это контрол из `winforms`, и WPF не может рисовать поверх него, т.к. это отдельное окно.